# Is it correct to use "...and as a result,..." to link two independent clauses? Is the comma after "result" necessary?

Tags: punctuation, commas, clauses

I ran into this sentence:

> I grew up in a home with two different cultures and as a result, I got to experience firsthand how misunderstandings evolve due to not understanding each other's culture.

These are two independent clauses while the second has an introductory clause.
Is that actually possible and do you have to use the comma after "result" then??

Comment: As Paul suggests, "as a result" is parenthetical and should be set off on BOTH ends by a comma.

Comment: ... Yes, balance is needed. '... as a result ...' doesn't need commas, but here zero punctuation is a non-starter. You could alternatively argue that 'and as a result' is a compound linker linking two independent clauses, and put commas either side of this.

Answer (score 4):

The usage you have shown is incorrect.

Anything parenthetical, i.e. anything that can be optionally dropped, needs to be surrounded by commas. In this case there should be a comma after the "and" in order to surround "as a result". British and American comma usage can vary but this is one thing these two cultures are united on.